How to measure CPU usage of an async function
Given an arbitrary async function in Node.js, is there any way to properly measure the CPU usage of that function, including all of its async microtasks?
I thought async_hooks was the way to do this, but I'm not sure how and it's now marked as deprecated. The deprecation notice links to AsyncLocalStorage for context tracking (which we use already) and this new diagnostics_channel API, which seems unhelpful and irrelevant to this (although the documentation for that is so unclear that I could be wrong).
Note that this is for continuous monitoring of a large system, so using the debugger is not relevant. At the moment we've just got the overall CPU usage of the process, but it would be more much helpful if we could break this down to get metrics for different parts of the system.
Comparison with measuring synchronous functions
You can measure CPU usage for arbitrary synchronous functions like this:
const start = process.cpuUsage();
foo();
console.log(process.cpuUsage(start));
// { user: 1995464, system: 6874 }

It doesn't matter what else the system is doing, the execution of foo blocks all of that (at least in JS-land, we're ignoring node internals), so the result is that the reported usage is the usage of foo.
But now consider that foo is an async function which we await instead. foo itself may have many awaits internally, and we have no idea what the rest of the system is doing in-between. Consider what happens if foo looks like this:
async function foo() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
}

This clearly uses practically zero CPU. But the reported CPU from our simple process.cpuUsage() measurement includes everything else the system is doing whilst we wait for foo to resolve, so the result may be very high, which is completely misleading.

I mean... depending on the async task in question it may not even be the node process that is consuming resources for any given async task.

I'm only interested in the CPU usage within the node process, external resource usage is obviously way out of scope here

Wouldn't any processing it is actually doing be synchronous, and thus picked up by general cpu usage tracking? while it's waiting for a thing to occur/finish obviously it's not doing anything if we're ignoring external resources.

Put another way, there's nothing special about asynchronous code that would cause it to consume resources any differently from any other javascript code. It's just code that gets ran when it's time for it to run, just like any other js code.

@KevinB correct, but the entire point of the question is if there are multiple async functions running "in parallel" then how do you capture the CPU usage for their various bits of sync code and assign it to the right one?

well, that's just it... nothing in javascript runs parallel on the main thread. If it's happening in parallel it's either 3rd party or it's a worker. async/await is no different than a setTimeout conceptually.

@KevinB, that's why I quoted "in parallel". Obviously it's not in parallel like a true thread, but I'm not sure what other term to use. Given two arbitrary async functions (which could each have many awaits internally), their various bits of execution are arbitrarily interleaved, and this is what makes it hard to get separate CPU usage for them. And yes, things like setTimeout are part of the same problem.

At that point, wouldn't breaking out reporting on "async" functions be no different than breaking out reporting on any other individual function?

@KevinB, no, it's easy to get usage for synchronous functions, but not for async. I've updated the question to show some examples for comparison.

You could potentially run the functions in node child processes. And then find the process PID and then ask the system for information about that PID.
The process of getting information from the PID varies from system to system depending on the OS and bash commands available, however I was able to find this module to simplify the process.
yarn add pidusage

npm install pidusage

const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const pidusage = require('pidusage')

const child = spawn('node', ['childScript.js'], {
    detached: true, // Allow the child process to continue running independently of the parent
    stdio: 'ignore' // Ignore the child process output
});

const { pid } = child;

pidusage(pid, (err, stats) => {
  console.log({
    cpu: stats.cpu,
    mem: stats.memory
  })
});

// Or in an asynchronous function

const { cpu, memory } = await pidusage(pid);
console.log({ cpu, memory });


You might consider using a Flame Graph for that. It would give you more context than watching a single async function.
https://nodejs.org/en/learn/diagnostics/flame-graphs

So sorry to bother you with unhelpful ideas.
